# Unable to run javafx app on windows 8.1

Tags: java, windows, javafx

I made a javafx desktop application using intellij idea and packaged it as given in [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/java-fx-tab.html#d278867e501) link. It works fine on my pc which has windows 7. But when run on windows 8.1, it gives this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.validatePaintOp(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.validatePaintOp(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.renderGeneralRoundedPgram(Un
known Source)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.renderGeneralRoundedRect(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.fillRect(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.paintTiles(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknow
n Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseResourceFactory.clearTextureCache(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseResourceFactory.getCachedTexture(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseResourceFactory.getCachedTexture(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.validatePaintOp(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.validatePaintOp(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.renderGeneralRoundedPgram(Un
known Source)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.renderGeneralRoundedRect(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.fillRect(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.paintTiles(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknow
n Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So is it that javafx does not work on windows 8? I dont think its given anywhere like that. After all its a typical java application, so it should work if we have jre installed.

What could be the solution to this?

EDIT:

Here is something strange observed:

Artifacts built using intellij idea 12.0.4 are working fine on windows 8 as well. But when built throught intellij idea 13.0.1 are giving the error.

Comment: Which version of Java is installed on Win 7 and which one is on Win 8.1?

Comment: What update of JRE 7?

Comment: @brano on win 8.1 PC, update 60 and on my win 7 pc, I am not sure(perhaps 24) but java -version on cmd on my win 7 pc gives 1.7.0_17

Comment: I think that's an issue. I had same exception when I updated `JRE` to 1.7.0_40 or 45. Try by installing `JRE 8` on Win 8.1. But before of that, try by including `jfxrt.jar` dependency (it's either in jre7\lib or jre7\lib\ext folder) to project from 1.7.0_17 (your working JRE). Good luck.

Comment: Definitely try Java 8, the issue looks like a texture management one (JavaFX unable to allocate a graphics texture on the Win 8 machine) and texture management in JavaFX was much improved for Java 8.  I don't recommend packaging jfxrt.jar with your project.  If you continue to have issues with Java 8, [file a bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) which includes an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jewelsea I tried java 8, but to same consequence. However one strange observation I am putting in my question.See edit.